# SQL join 4 tables with WHERE query

Tags: sql

I am trying to join 4 tables together as shown in this diagram here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkMLo.jpg

The SQL query I have written returns all fields except `TExpiryDate` and I have not come across any examples online that can help me understand this. Please help.

```
SELECT tbPurchaseHeader.PurchaseDate, 
       tbSupplier.CompanyName, 
       tbPurchaseDetails.UnitCost, 
       tbPurchaseDetails.Quantity, 
       tbPurchaseDetails.Bonus, 
       tbpurchasedetails.BatchID,
       tbBatch.TExpiryDate
FROM   ((tbPurchaseDetails 
       INNER JOIN tbPurchaseHeader
               ON tbPurchaseDetails.PurchaseID = tbPurchaseHeader.PurchaseID) 
        LEFT JOIN tbBatch
               ON tbPurchaseDetails.BID = tbBatch.BID)
       INNER JOIN tbSupplier 
               ON tbPurchaseHeader.SupplierID = tbSupplier.SupplierID 
WHERE  tbPurchaseDetails.ProductID = ? 
ORDER  BY tbPurchaseHeader.PurchaseDate
```

Comment: remove parentheses and try again

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do you understand the difference between INNER and LEFT JOIN? "LEFT JOIN returns all rows from the left table, even if there are no matches in the right table". So there are probably some records in tblPurchaseDetails with no or invalid BID?

Comment: @jeroenh you're actually right! I checked back in the database and found out BID is actually not used >.< 
i'll have to find another link between the tables. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `BID` contains empty values in the database. I have decided to make links elsewhere to get the data. Thanks everyone for making me realise this.